# How to update UITableViewCell with information from detail view?

Tags: ios

I'm developing an app and I want to make it look like the settings page on iOS:

[image]

The behavior I want to replicate is the one found at the cells "From/To" and "Allow Calls From". If you notice, those cells show the data the user inserted. How can I replicate that?

First of all, I'm fairly new to iOS, so whatever I came up with might not be the best solution for my case.

This is what I thought about doing (adding a label to the right and setting its value):

[image]

Is that the best approach? Also, how do I set that value? How should I go by after the user returned from the detail view to update that cell?

Comment: How much do you know about `UITablevIews`, reusing `UITableViewCells` and data persistence in iOS?

Comment: @Adeel well I do know about reusing cells (I'm making use of that technique). As for data persistence I'm using SQLite. But in this case I'm only concerned about persisting data between views and that I have zero knowledge about, hence my second question `How should I go by after the user returned from the detail view to update that cell?`    Thanks!

Comment: There are two ways to update the cell when the user returns from the detail view. 1) `Protocols` 2) `Notifications`. I would suggest that you go with the first option. Which language are you using BTW?

Comment: Whenever the value changes in the detail view you can notify the previous view of that change through a `protocol` method or a `notification`.

Comment: @Adeel thanks :) I'm actually using Xamarin.iOS, but you can give me an example in swift and I'll be able to translate it :)

Comment: you can use blocks to get live info once the data changed in the details view without getting into protocols & NSNotifications hassle

Comment: @MhammedMohie thank you, but how's that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to update the content in the previous view (we call it `FirstViewController`) when some value changes in the detail view. One possible way to do this is through `Protocols and Delegates`. Assuming that you already know about `storyboards` and `segues` here's an example. This example simply changes text of a `UILabel` in the `FirstViewController` when a button is pressed in the `DetailViewController`.

Lets start with `DetailViewController`. You want to observe changes in this scene and update data in the other scene accordingly. So you need to define a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) in this class.

```
protocol DetailDelegate {
    func updateCellWith(_ data:String)
}
```

Complete definition of this class would look like this:

```
import UIKit

protocol DetailDelegate {
    func updateCellWith(_ data:String)
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: DetailDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//On button tap the cell content will change in the previous scene through the delegate method
@IBAction func didTapBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.updateCellWith("Cell updated")
}
}
```

The `FirstViewController` will be the `delegate` of the `DetailViewController` and will conform to the `DetailDelegate`. You will set the `FromViewController` as the delegate of the `DetailViewController` before the transition.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DetailDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// Mark Navigation

@IBAction func moveToDetailVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    vc.delegate = self
}
}
```

On the button tap the `DetailViewController` will pass a string `Cell updated` to the `FirstViewController` through the delegate method `updateCellWith:`.

Comment: My pleasure .