# How to get back textfield data from tableViewCell in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitableview

I have two `tableViewControllers`, second tableViewController tableViewCell has `textField` and `imageView`, how can I get data from that `textfield` when I click `navigationBarBackButton` (I want to store that data in first `tableViewController`).

```
// code from second tableViewController...
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];

      cell.textLabel.text = @"SIM Name";
      cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"AirTel";
      cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Star2.png"];

     return cell;
   }

   TableViewCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
   cell1.nameTextField.delegate = self;


   if (indexPath.row == 1) {

      NSArray *cell1XibRef = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell1" owner:self options:nil];
      cell1 = [cell1XibRef objectAtIndex:0];
      cell1.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Con.png"];
      self.nameString = cell1.nameTextField.text;

      return cell1;
   }

  return nil;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  //Whenever people start editing your textfield

    self.nameString = textField.text;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.nameString);

 }
```

Comment: Use delegate pattern.

Comment: You can use delegate method or simply NSUserdefaults can be used aswell.

Comment: you can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) and create an event to send back the value that you want.

Comment: When i click back button it's not get the data from text field ....

Comment: self.nameString = cell1.nameTextField.text;

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40095168/3807336

Comment: if NSLOG(@"%@", self.nameString); it not show the data, means it's not get the data from text field why?

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to do that but I prefer this way

Save the `textfield.text` value in `NSUserDefaults` like this

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"controllerTwo"];
```

And get that value in first controller

```
NSString *secondContrllerText = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"controllerTwo"];
```

Comment: ok, before to set data, first it's need to get the data from textfield na. But it's not getting the data from textfield why?

Comment: Once if data come from textfield them only we can assign that data to either string or naUserDefaults.....

Comment: When you are clicking on navigationBarbackbutton then try to get textfield text and assign to userdefaults

Comment: Try to set tags to textfields and get data based on that tags

Comment: self.nameString = cell1.nameTextField.text;   NSLog(@"%@", self.nameString); i write this two lines but it printing anything...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136446/discussion-between-vadlani-marking-and-himanth).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add cells in one array and loads cells from that array which will returns you latest cell with all your edits.

```
NSMutableArray *arrCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (init i=0; i<20; i++){
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    arrCells = cell;
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell = arrCell[indexPath.row];
     ......
     return cell;

}
```

Comment: You can get your data back from here. Set Textfield tag as indexPath.row value. From there you can get back.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code i like to pass the data with block.here is the code  wish to help you.

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


 - (void)buttonClick
 {
     ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
     controller.passTheTextFieldData = ^(NSString *textValue){
         NSLog(@"show the  %@ textValue",textValue);
     };
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
 }

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^passTheTextFieldData)();

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *textValue;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}


- (void)textFieldValueChanged
{
    self.textValue = self.textField.text;
}

- (void)navigationbarBackClick
{
    if (self.passTheTextFieldData) {
        self.passTheTextFieldData(self.textValue);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: that's the same! i just show you the solution, if you every tableViewCell       have a textfield.    the correct thing  is to create a model or NsMutableArray to store all the data,and then  pass the data through block to the firstViewContoller.

Answer (score 0):

**Either you can use `delegate` method to store your value or use `NSUserdefaults`.But you have to store one value to pass it to another table view i recommend you to use `NSUserdefaults`.**

//suppose you have to save text (get your data)

```
NSString *valueToSave = cell1.nameTextField.text;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"keyAbcd"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

//another page where you want to show your data (paste your data)

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"keyAbcd"];//your key have to be same
//print save value in nslog
```

Comment: if we want to store data in NSUserDefaults first we need to fetch data...but it's not coming.....

Comment: Yes, You have to fetch first to store data in NSUserdefaults. If you not getting a data so you can't able to store data in defaults.

Comment: store data NSString *valueToSave = cell1.nameTextField.text;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"keyabcd"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"keyabcd"];
//print saved value

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag property for textField in tableViewCell

Then loop through the cells

for (int i = 0 ; i < [cellDataArray count] ; i++) {

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITextField *txtfield = [[cell contentView]viewWithTag:2];

    //now get the text txtfield.text
```

}

Hope this helps